# Design with Elementor and code the rest?

Tags: php, themes

Do you guys know if it is possible to design a website using Elementor or any other editor and then coding the rest using my custom PHP code?

I tried to use a theme downloaded from the internet and when I started editing with Elementor the design does not reflect on theme files, hence I cannot add code to the website.

I am asking this as I think designing the website will take a lot of time for that purpose I want to use a theme from the internet and edit using Elementor then add my custom code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use a drag and drop page builder like Elementor to edit the design of a custom-coded theme. If you really want to use Elementor, you could use Elementor Pro's theme builder to recreate the original theme manually.